# create dynamically named columns in a df inside a loop with R

Tags: r

I want to name all columns of a df after a specific value of an integer vector named 'content', which length is around 8000.

```
for (i in 1:length(content)) {
  colnames(df[i]) <- content[i]
}
```

Instead of having a df with columns named after content[i] values, I get a df with columns named: V1, V2, ..., Vn

Comment: R does not like names that start with digits. Also, for future reference, the `for` loop is totally unecessary: `colnames(df)[3:length(content)+2L] <- content` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

In R, you just to need to do:

```
colnames(df) <- content
```